# MVC Number Input Being Treated as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using a form (with `Html.BeginForm`), I have an `input` with type `number`. When I submit it like so:

[image: input type number]

I get the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'AmountOnHand' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Ingredient(Int32, System.String, Int32,
>   System.String)' in 'BrewReport.Web.Controllers.AdminController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

The form (simplified) is as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Ingredient", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input id="AmountOnHand" type="number" class="form-control" min="0" required="required" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Save Changes to Ingredient" />
}
```

Here is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateIngredient(string ingredientName, decimal amountOnHand, string measurementUnit)
{
    IngredientsData.SaveIngredient(ingredientName, amountOnHand, measurementUnit);
    return RedirectToAction("ManageIngredients");
}
```

Comment: You need to show the controller method and view

Comment: See Mun's answer, but you have not shown the correct code anyway - the error message is related to a POST method named `Ingredient()` which has 4 parameters, but the POST method you have shown is `CreateIngredient` and only has 3 parameters. And ALWAYS use strongly typed html helpers.

Comment: Also suggest you add validation attributes to your model properties so you get both server side and client side validation in conjunction with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and post back you model rather than individual parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Your input field is missing the `name` attribute, so when it gets posted back to the server, there is no value supplied and your code breaks.

You can fix this using one of the following methods:

**Add the `name` attribute to your input field.**

```
<input id="AmountOnHand" name="AmountOnHand" type="number" class="form-control" min="0" required="required" />
```

**Use the Html Helper to generate your field markup**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AmountOnHand, new { @type="number", @class="form-control", min="0", required="required" });
```

This will also add the name attribute for you, and has the added benefit of being strongly typed, in case you change the property name in future.

Comment: Here's what I had originally, before changing it to the code I posted above because I thought that was the problem: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AmountOnHand, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = "0", required = "required" })`

You're right that I forgot the `name` attribute though.

Comment: @muttley91 No probs, glad you got it working.  I'd definitely recommend using the HTML Helpers where possible.  They help to keep the code manageable and are a very helpful when refactoring and making changes later on.

Comment: Actually the HTML helper had the problem too (I generally agree that they should be used whenever possible).